# TFS and Post-Commit

Tags: dvcs, commit, post-commit

Does TFS 2010 have an SVN Post-Commit event ?
I want to run a script or an app or do stuff every time a developer checks in something. I've looked over the internet but didn't find something about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to create (and publish) a web service and subscribe to the event.  DotNetCurry has a decent article on the mechanics of wiring up the event.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=330&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1